# Export large Excel/CSV (10-20K records)

Tags: laravel, phpexcel, export-to-csv, maatwebsite-excel

I need to export Excel (CSV is ok) where will be about 10-20K records. I tried to export the package Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel ( https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel ). It works perfectly for small amount of records but does not work for this large files.

What could be the way around this situation?

Comment: can you post your code? Would be nice to understand what you're exporting (e.g. model, query, view, etc.)

Comment: If you can work with CSV, then create a CSV directly rather than using Laravel-Excel/PHPExcel; otherwise you're creating a lot of overhead that is necessary for genuine Excel format spreadsheet files, but completely unnecessary for simple CSV files